# How to make a text non copiable?

Tags: html, laravel

I want to make it hard for the viewers to copy the text; On a website, they put every word in a span tag so it would be harder to copy it from the page source and I wanted to know how to do that easily.
Is there any other similar methods?

Comment: If the text is shown, it can be copied, either by copying it, viewing HTML source and copying from there, typing each character manually, etc... What's the reason for this requirement?

Comment: @TimLewis My project view contains a long text that is very important to the essence of the project. I want to make it a little hard for someone to copy it.

Comment: That's an odd requirement... You could save it as an image maybe? Text in an image can't be copied. The answer below shows a method of making it harder, but as I said, you can still copy from source/element view in any browser.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really make text not copyable if you show it. You can make it a little hard tho.

```js
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
```

```css
.donottouch {
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="donottouch">
text
</div>

<img src="http://www.placekitten.com/200/300" width="200px" height="300px"/>
```

If you really want to make it hard save the text as a picture and add that to the page instead. Then you can't copy the content by inspecting the html. To make it a little harder you can disable rightclicks on a page with `document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());` making it harder to rightclick the image and save as. You can still grab the image from the html source, and open it in a new window. 
So to sum up there is no way to make content on your site 100% noncopyable, you can always grab content from a public site.

Comment: It didn't do anything!

Comment: @HoseinShendabadi what diden't you do?

Comment: @HoseinShendabadi Seriously? The image can be right-clicked and saved... And even if you prevented that, what's the stop someone from taking a screenshot of the image? Maybe consider not showing this text if privacy is such a concern...

Comment: No not really, people can always take a screenshot and save that way, if you show information you will always be subjectable to people copying your content. I have updated my answer with an image solution.